# Macro causes compiler error with name of NSString variable

Tags: objective-c, macos, c-preprocessor

I am trying to define a macro like this:

```
#define LogMethod(uuid) [LogManager logString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__] uuid:(uuid)];
```

and call it like this:

```
NSString *stringUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
LogMethod(stringUUID)
```

however I get a compiler error

> No known class method for selector 'logString:stringUUID:'

It seems it is passing `stringUUID` as a string and not the string of the object. Is it possible to pass an object to a C macro like this?

Comment: there is nothing C left here, it is purely an objective-C issue...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's not true; this is caused by the preprocessor, and the rules of that are defined by C.

Comment: @JoshCaswell ah so it seems, I hadn't scrolled right enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor is getting confused with the `uuid:uuid` bit and expanding it to `stringUUID:stringUUID`.

Try:

```
#define LogMethod(x) [LogManager logString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__] uuid:(x)];
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. That is so obvious now it's pointed out. I couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: @Darren There is a reason why people use variables like `__X__` in macros.